# Can I use Spring Data JPA in a Java Application (not Spring project)?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I created a simple Java application and use Hibernate to deal with postgres database. I want to use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate in my project. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am having a hard time reconciling "Can I use Spring in a non-Spring project."  If you use Spring JPA, then it's a Spring project.

Comment: What is your definition of "spring project"? You can use spring for plain (non-webserver) java applications in case that's what you mean. But spring-data-jpa depends on spring-core, it can't be used on its own.